# State space model for control with a force sensor

Tags: forces

Some background, Im making a electric assisted bicycle trailer( 1 axel, 2 wheel with hubmotors) that is going to be pulled by a bicycle, the motors are torque controlled(very accurate and precise control from the motor drivers. I can give torque instructions and will receive that torque instant). There is a force sensor attatched to the bar connecting the trailer to the bicycle. The force sensor(load cell) is designed to only measure the "translative force" meaning any rotation from the bicycle wont be measured.
I can measured the velocity from each wheel aswell as the force.

The goal is to control the motor torques for the two wheels to minimize the the "wheight of the trailer" for the rider.
I want to use some model based regulator like LQR.

I got stuck at the moddeling part, im using matlab for this project.

I figured i wanted my states to be some combination of the linear velocity, angular velocity and maybe the sensor value? I would probobly have to estimate the force from the side when turning the bike but at first im just asuming full state feedback ska having access to all states.
I would also like tk put a Cost on the input rate of change or something to make the change in control signals be penalized to have some tuning capabilities on the jerk.

Sum of the forces acting on the system and sum of the torques acting.
Cant get past how to include the sensor value as a state as I dont know how to write the state space for it.
Im thinking of a linear model or atleast just at the first part simplify it to a linear model:
x_dot =Ax + Bu
Y = cx +Du

Any tips, articles, equations, half-done or all-done models are more then welcome. Thanks